# Receiving Database Change Notifications in Oracle Using BizTalk Server

Tags: xml, oracle, biztalk

I have implemented Database Change Notifications concept using BizTalk in Oracle but I am not getting `RowId` which is the main field for me when any changes happened. I am getting output as below,

[image: Notification Response Message]

How can get the Row ID?

The second problem is whenever any changes are happening in my database the Notification is not coming until and unless I run the below query in my database

```
grant change notification to UserName
```

How can I make these permissions persist?

Answer (score 0):

Option 3 is what you need to enable.

From [Registration Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm#BDCIDBFJ) Developing Applications with Database Change Notification

> Registration Properties
>
> Oracle Database supports the following options for an object registration:
>
> 1. Purge On Notify option: Unregistering after the first change notification.
> 2. Timeout option: Specification of a registration expiration after a time interval.
> 3. `ROWID`s option: `ROWID`s of changed rows are part of the notification `ROWID` option.
> 4. Reliable Notification option: By default, notifications are generated in shared memory. If this option is chosen, notifications are generated in a persistent database queue. The notifications are enqueued atomically with the transaction that changes a registered object. Since the notifications are persistent in the database, if an instance crashes after generating a notification, they can be delivered when it restarts subsequently OR by a surviving instance of the cluster if running RAC. (Note: there is a trade-off involved here between performance of notifications and reliability. Since there are CPU and I/O costs when generating reliable notifications, it is recommended to choose the default in memory option if better notification performance is desired).
> 5. Operations filter: Ability to be notified of PARTICULAR operations (for example notifications only for `INSERT` AND `UPDATE`).
> 6. Transaction Lag: Specification of a count between successive notifications.
>
> If the ROWID option is chosen, then ROWIDs of changed rows are published as part of the notification. The ROWIDs are published in the external string format. From the ROWID information in the notification, the application should be subsequently able to retrieve the contents of the changed rows by performing a query of the form "SELECT * from table_name_from_notification where ROWID = rowid_from_notification". The length of the ROWID is 18 character bytes in the case of regular heap tables. In the case of Index Organized Tables (IOTs), the length of the ROWID depends on the size of the primary key and therefore could be larger than 18 bytes.
>
> The ROWID notifications are hierarchically summarized. If enough memory is not available on the server side to hold ROWIDs, then the notification might be rolled up into a FULL-TABLE-NOTIFICATION (a special flag in the notification descriptor is reserved for this purpose). When such a notification is received, the application must conservatively assume that the entire table (that is, all rows) may have been modified. ROWIDs are not part of such a notification. ROWIDs may be rolled-up if the total shared memory consumption due to ROWIDs is too large (exceeds 1% of the dynamic shared pool size), OR if too many rows were modified in a single registered object within a transaction (more than 80 approximately) OR if the total length of the logical ROWIDs of modified rows for an IOT is too large (exceeds. 1800 bytes approximately.).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is very easy:
you need to add ROWID in you select in BizTalk Receive Location, like this:

```
   SELECT ROWID, [your other column names here] FROM TIACODEV.EMP_DETAILS [WHERE if you need it]
```

not sure how to fix your second problem